# CakePHP beforeFilter find

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I love and hate Cakephp at the same time.
I need the current domain name and id in virtually every controller in a multi tenant site.

So, in the AppContoller beforeFilter...if I do this...

```
$dname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$this->set('domain',$dname); //only to show test output in the view.
```

I have access to $domain in the view without any problem.
Good so far. I know I have access to SERVER vars.
Then, my find function works fine when I hard code the domain name like this...

```
$this->loadModel('Domain');     
$domainName = $this->Domain->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Domain.name' =>'test.localhost.com')));
```

However, when I try to use $dname within the condition like this, it fails.

```
$this->loadModel('Domain');
$dname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];    
$domainName = $this->Domain->find('first',array('conditions' => array('Domain.name' => $dname)));
```

I'm feeling like I'm close, but... wth?

Comment: check the value of $dname

Comment: That's available in that first snippet. I have access to $dname in the view if I set it.

Comment: When you writing last code ? In Model or in Controller ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gosh. I am so embarrassed. It works fine. I didn't have an entry in the db for the domain I was using, so it couldn't find anything. Sorry. 
Sometimes that whole forest/trees thing.... well you know.

Comment: You are better of putting `Configure::write('x.domain', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` in e.g. `app/Config/bootstrap.php` and refering to `Configure::write('.x.domain')` instead of a the server global. Otherwise it's not possible to modify (if the need arose), it's harder to test, and makes using the same code via cli harder also.

Answer (score 0):

You can pr($dname); within the before filter and it will show on every page. also you may want to try using strtolower() to make sure that no other letters are capitalized when putting it in the condition.

Comment: ok pr($dname) shows that value on every page like we would expect. And I set it strtolower() and tried the query again. Still shows an empty array.